# Could "being" be omitted in "spend time (being) someone"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, verbs, literature, omissibility

I came across a sentence in Maugham's *The Moon and Sixpence* that I don't quite comprehend:

> They may **spend** their whole lives **aliens** among their kindred, and remain aloof among the only scenes they have ever known.

As far as I know, we can say "spend time on something / (in) doing something / being something", but I'm not aware that "being" can be omitted. Is this a grammatically correct use? Or did I get it wrong?

Thanks very much!

Comment: I would say that _as_ or _like_ is implied, rather than _being_ (they spend their lives as though they were aliens).

Comment: @KateBunting that should be the answer. :)

Comment: People of recognised calibre tend to redefine rather than break laws. 

I'd say this is a borderline grammatical but rare usage nowadays. As written, it is a subject-orientated depictive construction (compare 'He died a hero', though 'He gave his life a hero' sounds unacceptable). If a deletion, one cannot deduce without further knowledge whether as, like, being or living as/like have been omitted from an original.

Comment: @Greybeard 'I would say' _answers_  are explicitly suboptimal (and I'm using a euphemism) on ELU. Answers having supporting references are in the spirit of the site. Kate's comment is a good comment, which I can upvote. // I can't find decent comparable ("they spend their whole lives slaves / thralls / ..." or parallel "they live their whole lives slaves / ..." on the internet, or I'd post an answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There's a whole book: "Twelve Years a Slave."

Comment: @ Greybeard But no hits for "were twelve years slaves", and I think 2 different hits for "he was twelve years a slave", in a Google search. There's a whole book called 'Bombproof your Horse',  and quite a few hits for "bombproof horse", but that doesn't make the string natural-sounding. Though 'was twelve years a slave' sounds an awful lot better than 'spend their lives aliens' (the padding of 'whole' makes some difference). Depictive constructions are not very productive, not an open set.

Comment: *They may spend their whole lives **living as** aliens among their kinfolk.*

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. Your comment cast a new light on this long-puzzled-me question, and I really appreciate that!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You provide some really great insights of the way to read these classic lines - they really tend to "redefine rather than break laws." Thank you!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I used to think of that but later realized it might not be solid, for we usually don't omit the _**doing**_. Thank you all the same!